# change div depending on hour of day with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Anyone who wants to take a stab at this, I could really use your help!

I have a couple lines of php, that switches out a js file depending on the day of the week.
in each js file, I need it to hide/show a div depending on the hour. For some reason this isn't working. any ideas?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

//initialize on-air functions for Sunday... Yay it's Jesus day!
    var d = new Date();
    var currentHour = d.getHours(); //0-23

    if (currentHour > 5 && currentHour < 6) 
     { 
         $('#no_onair').hide();
         $('#newdimesion_onair').show();


      }
      else if (currentHour > 6 && currentHour < 7) 
     { 
         $('#no_onair').hide();
         $('#artfthesong_onair').show();


      }
      else if (currentHour > 8 && currentHour < 10) 
     { 
         $('#no_onair').hide();
         $('#thejazzshow_onair').show();


      }

    else if (currentHour > 11 && currentHour < 13) 
     { 
         $('#no_onair').hide();
         $('#rob_onair').show();


      }


      else if (currentHour > 13 && currentHour < 14) 
     { 
         $('#no_onair').hide();
         $('#nick_onair').show();


      }

       else if (currentHour > 16 && currentHour < 18) 
     { 
         $('#no_onair').hide();
         $('#stadler_onair').show();



      }
    else {
       $('#no_onair').show();
       }

setTimeout(function() {
     $('#fixed_onair').addClass('animated fadeInDown');
     $('#fixed_onair').show();
},  5100);

});
```

Comment: `currentHour > 5 && currentHour < 6` will always be false. Same as `currentHour > 6 && currentHour < 7` and `currentHour > 13 && currentHour < 14`

Comment: if (currentHour >= 5 && currentHour <= 6) etc.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that out, and let you know if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i am not sure why you would use php to swap JS files. The easiest way to do this is to assign CSS classes to your divs and then just use jQuery to hide/show.

Below is a snippet that works. This will display the correct div on load. If you want to swap them out dynamically for people already on the site you can set a timer that checks every xx minutes and run the same code. The each loop can probably be optimized if need be, but does not seem you have that many divs. either way, much better than using PHP to inject scripts.

```html
<div class="all d0 h1 h2 h3 h4" style="display:none;"> Sunday 1, 2, 3, 4 </div>
<div class="all d0 h5 h6 h7 h18" style="display:none;"> Sunday 5, 6, 7, 18 </div>
<div class="all d1 h1 h2 h3 h4" style="display:none;"> Monday 1, 2, 3, 4 </div>
<div class="all d1 h5 h6 h7 h8" style="display:none;"> Monday 5, 6, 7, 8 </div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("div.all").hide();
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDay();
        var h = date.getHours();
        console.log('searching for ' + d + ' and ' + h);
        $("div.all").each(function() {
            if ( $(this).hasClass("d" + d) && $(this).hasClass("h"+h) ) {
                $(this).show();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: I'm making an on-air section for a radio station... and I thought it would be easiest to manage if I split the js into individual days. So for each day, it would display the dj currently playing. So I'm just using php to grab the day of the week, and insert the correct javascript for that day... and it's about 20+ Dj's...  Is this incorrect?

Comment: if the div content is static, just name of the dj and static blurb/picture/... i would just do the whole thing in javascript as i outlined above. Just give each div the identifying CSS classes for days and hours, and use jquery to show the matching ones. I would then do a setInterval than runs every 1 minute to execute the code, just in case somebody has their browser open all day. above code should work perfectly for you.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This works great! How could I put minutes in there as well?

Comment: The trick is to make sure your CSS classes match your needs. For minutes you can add m1, m2... classes but that will soon become cumbersome. If there is a pattern to the minutes (or the overall calendar) you can just create class names based on the pattern: e.g. d0s1_15e8_30 for a Sunday show that starts at 1:15 and ends at 8:30 and then based on the time/day construct a class name dynamically and apply the same logic above.